# Difference between `git rebase foo bar` and `git checkout bar; git rebase foo`?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase, git-checkout

I've seen both, and they seem to do the same thing.

1)   `git rebase foo bar`

2)  `git checkout bar`; 
`git rebase foo`

Are they the same?  And, does it depend on which branch you are on when you do 1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the same things.  Take a look at the documentation on [`git-rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

> If  is specified, git rebase will perform an automatic git checkout  before doing anything else. Otherwise it remains on the current branch.